# how to count number of dictionary in set of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcFTj.png)I am trying to convert a very complex JSON into CSV, and now I have stuck somewhere in the middle. My JSON file is nested with a combination of many lists and dictionaries(dictionaries also have sub dictionaries)

while I am iterating through the complete JSON, I am getting two dictionaries from a for a loop. Now my problem is when I am looping through this set, to append keys(Zip1) and values(value) into my default dictionary which is set as null in the beginning, due to the limitation of dictionaries, I am able to extract only one value i.e. Zip1, 34567

```
{'type': 'Zip1',  'value': '12345'}
{'type': 'Zip1',  'value': '34567'}
```

```
fin_data={}


dict1 is the outcome of some for loop of my code and holds the value as 
{'type': 'Zip1',  'value': '12345'}
{'type': 'Zip1',  'value': '34567'}


for key,value in dict1.items():
    for data in value:
       print(data)
       fin_data.update(key:data['value'])
```

Is there any way, I can iterate through sets of the dictionaries of the dict1?
so that at the first iteration, I will copy data into CSV, and then in the second iteration, the other values to my CSV

The output I am getting is  :

`{Zip1:34567}`

Actual Output is required as  both values
Sample of my json, on which i am working, Need to extract data from all of the value attributes:

```
{
  "updatedTime": 1562215101843,
  "attributes": {
    "ActiveFlag": [
      {
        "value": "Y"
      }
    ],
    "CountryCode": [
      {
        "value": "United States"
      }
    ],
    "LastName": [
      {
        "value": "Giers"
      }
    ],
    "MatchFirstNames": [
      {
        "value": "Morgan"
      }
    ],
    "Address": [
      {
        "value": {
          "Zip": [
            {
              "value": {
                "Zip5": [
                  {
                    "type": "Zip1",
                    "value": "12345"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ],
          "Country": [
            {
              "value": "United States"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "value": {
          "City": [
            {
              "value": "Tempe"
            }
          ],
          "Zip": [
            {
              "value": {
                "Zip5": [
                  {
                    "type": "Zip1",
                    "value": "85287"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}


Expected Result :

updatedTime, ActiveFlag, CountryCode, LastName, MatchFirstNames, Address_Zip_Zip5, Address_City, Address_Country

1562215101843,Y,United States,Giers,Morgan,12345,,United States
1562215101843,Y,United States,Giers,Morgan,85287,Tempe,
```

Comment: each time you have updated fin_data for same key thats why you get the last one only

Comment: dictionary cannot have duplicate keys, and I have to apend values from that loop....that is really required, else I could have also not done so

Comment: [{'type': 'Zip1',  'value': '12345'},{'type': 'Zip1',  'value': '34567'}] is this your expected out put ?

Comment: yes, that can also help, but please consider that, i do not have separate dictionaries, like d1={'type': 'Zip1',  'value': '12345'} and d2 = {'type': 'Zip1',  'value': '34567'}. so I am not getting a solution on how to iteration through this object   {'type': 'Zip1',  'value': '12345'}  
             {'type': 'Zip1',  'value': '34567'}

Comment: can you paste here output of print(dict1)

Comment: I have added image in the description, please refer that. Before posting ques here, I did some changes in the code(posted here, so that it can be readable. Highlighted part is the one which is giving me output like this

Comment: Spell out the expected results. E.g. {'Zip1':[34567, 12345]} or {'Zip1': '34567 12345'} or may be you repeat a row with different zips several times

Comment: from your attached image it seems print(qq) prints : {'type': 'Zip1',  'value': '12345'}
{'type': 'Zip1',  'value': '34567'} , is it correct?

Comment: dict1 is not dictionary but set of dictionaries, right?

Comment: yes you are correct, now if i have to append these values to my dictionary, I will get only one set of values, so is there any work around of iterating through these list of dictionaries?

Comment: yes you are also right @Serge

Comment: provide your json (or a fragment of) and expected result

Comment: I have added my json data, in the description, please have a look, thanks alot

Comment: in your json data updatedTime appears only once but in your expected data it appears twice , I cant understand how. can you explain a bit.

Answer (score 0):

At the first step for each person accumulate all the zip codes in one line/list/record say space separated or in an array.

Then after everything extracted split row into several